# How to fix/workaround inconsistency in browser implementations of the transitionend event for CSS3 Transitions?

Tags: javascript, events, css, opera, css-transitions

I set up a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bodine30/6WssN/) to show some of the inconsistencies I'm noticing.

- Opera throws 'bonus' transition events for you to dodge...
- Firefox is probably as it should be, which is still frustrating...
- Chrome is predictably **great**, even making assumptions for me like `event.target.style["margin-left"]` giving the correct value instead of requiring me to use `event.target.style[event.propertyName.toCamelCase()]`

I'd like to know the cleanest possible unified approach to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately given the disparate state of browser implementations of the `transitionend` event it seems the best approach is to check that the `event.propertyName` ***REALLY*** is the property you are looking for. This can be done by checking it against a known `object` or `string` which contains a map of the properties that should be transitioning. The current solution I used:

```
function transitionEndHandler(event) {
    if(
        (
            (event.propertyName in event.target.style) && 
            // BLESS CHROME'S HEART THIS IS ALL I NEED TO CHECK FOR THEM

            (event.target.style.cssText.indexOf(event.propertyName) !== -1) 
            // FIREFOX WILL PASS THIS CONDITION, AS IT DOESN'T THROW EVENTS FOR PROPERTIES YOU DIDN'T SPECIFICALLY BIND

        ) || 
        (
            (event.propertyName.replace(/-([a-z])/gi, function(s, group1) {
            // OPERA SURE DOESN'T WANT TO MAKE THIS EASY, IT WONT FIND A 'margin-left' in STYLE
            // SO I HAVE TO LOOK FOR 'marginLeft' INSTEAD THIS MAKES event.propertyName and event.target.style
            // ESSENTIALLY USELESS INSIDE THE TRANSITIONEND EVENT HANDLER
                    return group1.toUpperCase();
                }) in event.target.style) && 
            (event.target.style.cssText.indexOf(event.propertyName) !== -1)
            // AGAIN WE HAVE TO CHECK TO MAKE SURE WE ACTUALLY 'SET' THIS STYLE PROPERTY ON THE ELEMENT
            // AS OPERA THROWS AN TRANSITIONEND EVENT FOR opacity WHEN YOU SET marginLeft
        )
    ) {
        // THIS EVENT.PROPERTYNAME, IS ACTUALLY A PROPERTY I TRANSITIONED,
        // NOT JUST ANY PROPERTY THE BROWSER DECIDED IT WANTED TO TRANSITION FOR ME
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To work around Opera I animated a property that wouldn't be visually evident

```
element.addEventListener(transition_event,function(ev){
    if(ev.propertyName == "min-width") {
      // do stuff;
    }
}, false);
```

This might (or not) suit your needs.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What exactly did animating this _unrelated_ property gain you? What were you _working around_ exactly, I had several issues with opera listed in the jsfiddle... thanks.