# CSS3 animation end techniques

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, css

So I wanted to open a dialog in the community about various techniques people have used to detect when an animation is ended.  Particularly when fading something out (read opacity).

Now I am not sure what other people have used, but I have found it particularly effective to use a timeout to wait for the animation to end, and then hide it, like so (using jQuery obviously):

```
$('#someDiv').css({'opacity':0});
setTimeout(function(){$('#someDiv').hide()}, 500);
```

where the CSS looks like this:

```
#someDiv {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

I am aware of the transition end bindings that most of the modern browsers have implemented, but I seriously dislike using them.  The seem a bit flaky and I hate having to loop over and set the listeners up.  Plus with each browser having a totally different event fired, it gets hairy.

What are some thoughts on the various techniques that are out there?  Since this is relatively new and undocumented, let's see what people have been using!

Thanks guys!
-Geoff

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an event for this called

```
transitionend
```

which makes much more sense than to use a `setTimeout`.

So you should go like

```
$('#someDiv').css({'opacity':0}).on('transitionend', function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

---

Since the name for that event-type can vary between browsers, I wrote a little helper:

```
var dummy           = document.createElement( 'div' ),
    eventNameHash   = { webkit: 'webkitTransitionEnd', Moz: 'transitionend', O: 'oTransitionEnd', ms: 'MSTransitionEnd' },
    transitionEnd   = (function _getTransitionEndEventName() {
        var retValue = 'transitionend';

        Object.keys( eventNameHash ).some(function( vendor ) {
            if( vendor + 'TransitionProperty' in dummy.style ) {
                retValue = eventNameHash[ vendor ];
                return true;
            }
        });

        return retValue;
    }());
```

So use that code to advance-conditional load the correct event name and then use the `transitionEnd` variable for the `.on()` binding name.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QBFtH/1/

Comment: Ahh now this is pretty much what I was looking for.  Seems to be a bit more foolproof.  Now would I want to call that helper in document.ready and save the value somewhere?

Comment: @gabaum10: I added an example

Comment: don't forget about http://stackoverflow.com/a/8511922/1048572, and the fact that changing a style property does not always cause a transition.

Comment: One issue I have found is you can't tell which transition is firing.  If you have multiple transitions on the page, there is a possibility of the event firing multiple times, causing all sorts of undesired effects.  How do you deal with that?

Comment: Hey jAndy, did you see my last comment?  Is that in scope for this question?  If not, I will open a new one and mark this one as closed.